# javascript prototype chaining - get parent of parent of

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've been reading about javascript prototype chaining and, as I understood, there is one global `Object.prototype` which is the base for other prototypes, such as `Array.prototype`, which can be the base for another prototype. Just like inheritance in class-based OOP. That's fine.

Now, I want to check and compare prototypes of distinct objects. If `Array`'s prototype is based on `Object.prototype`, I guess that something like `Array.prototype.prototype` should be possible. But it's undefined:

```
> Array.prototype.prototype
undefined
```

And when I type `__proto__` instead of `prototype`, I get:

```
> Array.__proto__
[Function: Empty]
> Object.__proto__
[Function: Empty]
> Array.__proto__.__proto__
{}
```

(console output is taken from nodejs). I've got following questions:

- how can I access "parent prototype" of a prototype?
- what's the difference between `prototype` and `__proto__`?

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're looking for:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Array.prototype);
// The same as Object.prototype
```

(Which is a ES5 feature, [not compatible with some older browsers](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.getPrototypeOf)).

> what's the difference between prototype and __proto__

The `prototype` property always belongs to a constructor function (like `Object`, `Array`, and custom constructors). The `__proto__` property exists on instances created with such constructors, and points to the same object as constructor.prototype.

For example:

```
function MyClass(){}
var myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.__proto__ === MyClass.prototype; // true
```

In the examples you gave, `Array.__proto__` is actually the prototype object of the constructor function – not its `prototype` property. That's why it's `[Function: Empty]`, because `Array` is a function, an instance of the default `Function` constructor. The `__proto__` of some specific array instance is the same as `Array.prototype`:

```
var arr = [];
arr.__proto__ === Array.prototype; // true
```

Comment: Not exactly. `Array.prototype` itself is "*the same as the `__proto__` of some array instance*", not its prototype.

Comment: @Bergi If that's about the comment that was on my first code block, you're right. Removed.